# Fit the image to the bordered radius view component react native

Tags: react-native, imagebackground

Current UI:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E30I4.png)

Expected UI: [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST2i3.png)

The question is how to fit the image to the bordered radius view component in react native?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

just set your view to to make like desire and the image inside it with resizeMode={'cover'} and width and height 100%

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '60%', borderBottomLeftRadius: '50%', borderBottomRightRadius: '50%' }}>
            <Image source={require(...)} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}} resizeMode={'cover'}/>
        </View>
      </View>
```